# About Architecture of Complex Modular Android Application

Tags: android, broadcast

The goal of this post is to obtain informations about "creation" of modular
complex application with Android.
I must developp a professionnal system application (communication with other devices, not an "desktop application")
I need some advices about architecture.
This application won't be available on Android Market.

In order to have a modular application, I want to create independant module.
So the architecture should be contain :
- some services (like Wifi communication, GPS listener, BlueTooth communication,..)
these services will run at the boot of the android device (smartphone, tablett,..).
they must be available every time as needed.
- one service will be in charge of instanciate module adn verifiy that services run and reboot service if it is not present.
- modules, they have broadcast receiver, and so they wake up when they catch the 'good" intent.
They do their task and create parcel object and broadcast the result all over the application.

The application should be contains many modules (may 10,50, 100 ? (for the moment I don't know the number of module)).
It's an application system, so the application must be reactive. For example, I have a module which communicate in WIFI with a radio Mobile in 40 Mhz, so I need to send
and receive data every 30-60 ms when I am "in communication".

So my real question is :
Is the system Android can support many modules which communicate with broadcast ?
For me, each module doesn't know the other modules. Each module have entries (many intent actions) and exit (many sendbroadcast).

If anyone have suggestion about the architecture.
Sorry for my english ^^.

Good day.